# Bluetooth and WIFI not working in KDE Neon but working fine in Windows 11. How to fix my Bluetooth and WIFI?

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, windows-11, kde, wifi-driver

I was using Windows 10 on my laptop then updated to Windows 11 and joined Windows Insider Program Developer Channel. After that all my drivers randomly keeps failing and I have to reinstall them manually. Then I left the Insider Program and reinstalled Windows 11 form scratch and totally cleaned my SSD. Even then my drivers keep failing. Then I read an reddit article to hard reset the laptop by pressing the power button for 60 seconds. This worked fine for me and everything was back to normal.

Then I installed KDE Neon on dual boot but my WIFI and Bluetooth is not working sometimes on KDE Neon. They both fail randomly whenever I start my laptop. Most of the time my WIFI is working but Bluetooth is totally out of service. Bluetooth is not even showing up in the setting. Everything is running fine in Windows 11. I tested Ubuntu live booted from my pen drive and there too WIFI and Bluetooth is not working.

Is there any fault in my hardware? I want to know what is happening and how to fix my WIFI and Bluetooth in KDE Neon.

Laptop - Asus TUF A15(2021 Model)
Ryzen 7 4800H
Nvidia RTX 3050

If you want others details please let me know.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` :

```
prabhakar@asustuf:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7961]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:4680]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
    Kernel modules: mt7921e
```

Comment: First of all when dual-booting with Windows disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must. It keeps drives in a semi-hibernated state and may hijack other devices and prevent correct hardware initialization when rebooting from Windows to the other OS. That said your WiFi/BT issue may not have to do with it. Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command so we can identify the hardware and try to find solutions.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I already disabled the fast boot mode. I edited my question and pasted the output of the command above.

Comment: Fast Boot is a UEFI feature; Fast **Startup** is a Windows feature. Disabling the former is optional but recommended most of the time; disabling the latter when dual-booting is a must. There's no sign of any meaningful edit (apparently all you did was adding the "kde" tag), please check and act accordingly.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I did as you said. I turned off fast startup from Windows setting and edited my question properly.

Comment: It show the correct driver being used. Check this Q&A for other suggestions: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=mt7921e